# Get X numbers from arrayA[5000] into arrayB[] in groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

```
 arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2];
```

I need to get separated numbers in groups like this:

```
arrayB = [1234,5678,9123,4567,8912];
```

As you can see its the same `arrayA` but in groups of 4 values that are now new numbers.

I was able to make it work with a bug like this: `arrayB=[undefined1234,undefined5678];`
with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (i/4== n+1){
            arrayB[n] = temp;
            n++;
        }
         temp += arrayA[i];
}
```

And thats it. I understand the bug, it is because of that `+=` but am not sure how to do this any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will do that trick

```
        var arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2,3,4];
        var arrayB = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < arrayA.length; x += 4) {
           arrayB.push(arrayA.slice(x, x + 4).join(''));
        }

        console.log(arrayB);
```

**Update**
Millie has raised a fair point. if you need numbers in the result array, use following statement in `for` loop

```
arrayB.push(parseInt(arrayA.slice(x, x + 4).join('')));
```

Comment: this works, but returns the arrayB[0] empty and in arrayB[1] and on everything is ok

Comment: Why'd you add elements to `arrayA`? It's creating a final `34` element in `arrayB`. That said, your answer handles both cases now and speaks javascript more fluently, so I will delete mine :).

Comment: @Tymofek are you sure no other code snippet is modifying `arrayB` since this code works fine for me.
@MillieSmith to show that it can create elements with whatever remains in `arrayA`.

Comment: Works Excellent!!! i had this written around arrayB[0]=""; xD
deleted that and everyhing its working now ;) ty guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `temp` to "" both before the loop starts and after each time you assign to `arrayB` (and when you make that assignment, turn the string in `step` into an integer).  And you may need to make a final assignment to `arrayB` after the `for` loop finishes.

Comment: There are still some type issues, no? 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, not 1234.

Comment: if i set temp to 0 it returns arrayB[0] = 01234;

Comment: no its like that i dont need 1+2+3+4 i need "1234" as a number

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2];
temp = arrayA.join('');

count = 4;

grouped = [];

max = temp.length / count;

for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

  grouped.push(parseInt(temp.substr(i * 4, 4)));

}

console.log(grouped);
```

Little numbers to strings conversion, and returning of numbers. :)
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hue0a1wb/